# Ubuntu 14.04 *.sty and *.cls files are missing?

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 on my laptop:

`sudo apt-get install texlive texlive-lang-german texlive-lang-english texlive-doc-en texlive-doc-de texlive-latex-extra latexmk`

Everything seemed to be fine but unfortunately I can not compile some of my tex-files. Some compile without errors, others say "file xxx.sty" or "yyy.cls" is missing / not found.

On my Windows 8 PC and my Ubuntu 12.04 Virtual Machine all tex-files can be compiled without errors.

What is missing?
Are those files something like stylesheets or so? Do they have to be in some directory? Why did apt-get did not install them?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get texlive-full` which should install everything. As seen here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/texlive-full there are many more packages than dreamt of in your command, Horatio.

Comment: If you want an alternative, one-command solution that will allow you to keep TeX Live updated, consider https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu (it has been tested on 14.04).

Comment: Yes, if they aren't found they are missing. They have to be installed. Apt-get did not install them because you only specified some certain parts of TeX Live which did not include the ones you apparently intended to use. And this is exactly the drawback of using the overhead of the linux-distribution-managed latex-distribution management and why I use the DVD install from tug.org. Hope that makes sense to you. :) But it should be resolved by using @bombcar's advice.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: You can use `apt-file search <filename>` to discover which package contains the file you are missing.

Comment: @bombcar - shouldn't it be `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` ?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. Try installing the following packages in order:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
...
```

In my case base and recommended were already installed. Installing `texlive-latex-extra` packages resolved my problem.